# Is there yet an example of a non-negative convex polynomial that cannot be written as a sum-of-squares?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, convexity, real-algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares

I have read that it remains an open question, whether an example can be constructed of a non-negative convex polynomial that **cannot** be written as a sum-of-squares. My reading includes the following post: [Polynomials that are sums of squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3569/polynomials-that-are-sums-of-squares)

However, the material I have found is generally not so recent, and so I simply wondered whether any examples have been discovered in more recent years?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you are implicitly also referring to https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0656 for an existence result...?

Comment: Sorry my post was vague in this regard. That is a useful reference, which "implies existence of convex forms that are not sums of squares, although there are still no known examples." As a reference from 2009, I wonder whether this still largely represents where we are today?

Comment: Brian, are you acquainted with the following? Amir Ali Ahmadi, Alex Olshevsky, Pablo A. Parrilo, John N. Tsitsiklis, [NP-hardness of Deciding Convexity of Quartic Polynomials and Related Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1908), December 2010.

Comment: I have read a really interesting paper by R. Bielawski, which constructs non-negative polynomials which are not sums of squares. But he does not mention convexity. I just mention it in case it could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Malkoun. It does seem that finding examples in the convex case is much harder as there do not seem to be any so far.

Comment: For clarity I have simplified this post and posted another more specific question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376728/can-i-prove-that-a-polynomial-representing-the-4th-moment-of-a-weighted-sum-of-r